# Is it possible to make number of 10 threads Which will be in an Arraylist?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it possible to make number of 10 threads Which will be in an Arraylist.
Can I take threads from that Arraylist and make the threads do the work and give it back to the Arraylist.
How can I do it
Here are the sample code

```
threads = new ArrayList<>(10);

for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    WorkerThread thread = new WorkerThread(threads);
    threads.add(thread);
    threads.add(thread);
    thread.start();
}
```

After doing the task can I remove it from Arraylist and again add it to The Arraylist to do another task.

Comment: This sounds almost exactly like what [ExecutorService.invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)) does.

Comment: Look up _thread pools in Java_ lots of hits

Answer (score 3):

## Executor service

Seems like you are re-inventing [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 ) ;
```

Submit your tasks as objects implementing [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) or `Callable`. The executor service handles assigning the task to an available thread.

Be sure to properly shutdown the executor service. See boilerplate code given in the Javadoc. Or automatically close using try-with-resources syntax.

Search Stack Overflow for more info and many examples.

### Virtual threads

If your tasks involve [blocking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing)) (they are not [CPU-bound](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound)), consider using [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) in Java 21+.

#### Example code

Here is example code. We start with ten inputs, a collection of `Integer` objects. Our task is to print each of these numbers to the console, concurrently. We create a new fresh virtual thread for each of these tasks. When complete, the virtual thread terminates and is then discarded.

```java
SequencedCollection < Integer > inputs = IntStream.rangeClosed ( 1 , 10 ).boxed ( ).toList ( );
try (
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor ( ) ;
)
{
    for ( Integer input : inputs )
    {
        Runnable task = ( ) -> System.out.println ( input );
        executorService.submit ( task );
    }
}
```

Run.

```
INFO - Demo begin. 2023-10-09T21:12:28.634400Z
1
6
7
8
10
3
2
4
5
9
INFO - Demo end. 2023-10-09T21:12:28.647095Z
```

Comment: I don’t want to use ExecutorService. I want to do it manually. 
Suppose from main method 
String message = "Hello from Main method";
         while(true) {
           threadPool.execute(message);
       }
I constantly give message to the threadpool

First I initialized 10 threads in a threadpool 
Like this

public ThreadPool(int numThreads) {
        threads = new ArrayList<>(numThreads);
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            threads.add(new WorkerThread(threads));
        }

Comment: Here first 10 threads will be started as this is the first time and print the message 10 times by 10 threads 
Now Let's assume that each thread takes different amount of time to print those messages 
Now I want to make a logic where the program will check at this moment how many threads are currently executing their task and becomes available 
Here I know that after execution the thread goes in terminated state and cannot be used again 
But I want to maintain that a fixed number of thread will do my task
I am getting the logic to make this program

Comment: (A) What you describe is exactly what `ExecutorService` does when backed by a thread pool. So there is no point to you re-inventing this except intellectual curiosity. If you are a curious about how to implement, go look at the source code in OpenJDK. (B) Virtual threads in Java 21+ largely eliminate the need for a thread pool, and eliminate your need for a limit of 10 threads.